# zf2 dispatch event triggered after my own?

Tags: events, zend-framework2, dispatch

why dispatch event is triggered after my own in my controller?

onBootstrap:

```
$sharedManager->attach('*', '*', function($e) {
    Debug::dump($e->getName());
});
```

indexAction:

```
$this->getEventManager()->trigger(__FUNCTION__ . '.pre', $this);
Debug::dump('indexAction do...');
$this->getEventManager()->trigger(__FUNCTION__ . '.post', $this);
```

Result is:

```
string(5) "route"
string(15) "indexAction.pre"
string(17) "indexAction do..."
string(16) "indexAction.post"
string(8) "dispatch"
string(8) "dispatch"
string(6) "render"
string(8) "renderer"
string(13) "renderer.post"
string(8) "renderer"
string(13) "renderer.post"
string(8) "response"
string(6) "finish"
string(12) "sendResponse"
```

I found dispatch process:
https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1OwFfjgaiXDuKmS2I8nnJNFqoDgEWNNB-_-tUXUPVrgQ/edit
but it seems that it's not correct

I thought that dispatch event will be triggered as dispatch.pre, not dispatch.post...

Comment: Interesting; just tried this and got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of debugging is giving you strange results.

By adding the 'debug listener' with a default event priority (which is `1`) the *output* of the event name actually happens *after* the dispatch event occurs.

This is due to the fact that ZF2 registers the controller's `dispatch` event first (also with an event priority of 1). So the event *happens* in the correct order; it's just your listener *outputs* at the wrong time.

You can test the order of events by adding one line to `Zend\EventManager\EventManager::trigger()`

```
// Zend\EventManager\EventManager
public function trigger($event, $target = null, $argv = array(), $callback = null)
{
    echo '<br>Triggered: ' . $event;
    //...
}
```

This output (excludes module bootstrap bits)

```
Triggered: bootstrap
Triggered: route
Triggered: dispatch // MVC dispatch
Triggered: dispatch // Action Controller disaptch
Triggered: foo.pre  // Controller custom events
Triggered: foo.post // Controller custom events
Triggered: render
Triggered: renderer
Triggered: renderer.post
Triggered: renderer
Triggered: renderer.post
Triggered: response
Triggered: finish
```